# how to connect bootstrap form to Django database to create a model instance

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-5

I am new to bootstrap and django both, so please don't mind my skills.
I have made a custom bootstrap form for my todo app that will add item in the database which looks like this [add task field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5q9U.png)
here is the bootstrap code:

```
<form method="post" class="form-control">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p class="lead">
        Create your task:
    </p>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your task here:" name="task">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your time here:" name="time">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect" name="status">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="1">In Complete</option>
                <option value="2">Completed</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Confirm</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the model and the form are below:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    choices = (
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ('In Complete', 'In Complete'),
    )
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=choices, null=True, blank=False)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *
from django import forms

class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

and the view is:

```
def create_task(request):
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'task/home.html', context)
```

what I'm asking is how can I connect this form to database, so it can create model instance.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to django!

if you are new to django it's better to follow official tutorial first

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/

I saw you made some progress but to fill the gaps quickly, tutorial is the best way

so after this I believe you will be able quickly answer your question